# XmlException - given illegal XML from 3rd party; must process

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

There are several SO questions and answers about this when creating an XML file; but can't find any pertaining to when you are given bad XML from a 3rd party that you must process; note, the 3rd party cannot be held accountable for the illegal XML.

Ultimately, the .InnerText needs to be escaped or encoded (e.g. changed to legal XML characters) - and later decoded after proper XML parsing.

QUESTION:  Are there any libraries that will `Load()` Invalid/Illegal XML files to allow quick navigation for such escaping/encoding?  Or am I stuck having to manually parse the invalid xml, fixing it along the way ... ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ChunkData>
  <Fields>
    <Field1>some words < other words</Field1>
    <Field2>some words > other words</Field2>
  </Fields>
</ChunkData>
```

Comment: There are many questions like this (https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+read+invalid+xml) and there is really no good solution - no built in XML readers would read such documents. Your best bet would be to grab HTML parser (like HtmlAgilityPack) and try to read the document before resorting to regex/String.IndexOf...

Comment: Thanks @AlexeiLevenkov; that was just the direction that I was looking/asking for - didn't have time to implement it that way unfortunately ... added a solution below, thoughts on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although HttpAgilityPack is awesome (and I'm using it in another project of my own), I was given no the time to follow Alexei's advice - which is exactly the direction that I was looking for -- can't parse it as XML?  cool, parse it as HTML ... didn't even cross my mind ...

Ended up with this, which does the trick (but is exactly what Alexei advised against):

```
private static string EncodeValues(string xml)
{
    var doc = new List<string>();
    var lines = xml.Split('\n');
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        var output = line;
        if (line.Contains("<Field") && !line.Contains("Fields>"))
        {
            var value = line.Parse(">", "</");
            var encoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value);
            output = line.Replace(value, encoded);
        }
        doc.Add(output);
    }
    return string.Join("", doc);
}

private static Hashtable DecodeValues(IDictionary data)
{
    var output = new Hashtable();
    foreach (var key in data.Keys)
    {
        var value = (string)data[key];
        output.Add(key, HttpUtility.UrlDecode(value));
    }
    return output;
}
```

Used in conjunction with an Extension method I wrote quite awhile ago ...

```
public static string Parse(this string s, string first, string second)
{
    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) return "";
        var start = s.IndexOf(first, StringComparison.InvariantCulture) + first.Length;
        var end = s.IndexOf(second, start, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
        var length = end - start;
        return (end > 0 && length < s.Length) ? s.Substring(start, length) : s.Substring(start);
    }
    catch (Exception) { return ""; }
}
```

Used as such (kept separate from the Transform and Hashtable creation methods for clarity):

```
xmlDocs[0] = EncodeValues(xmlDocs[0]); // in order to handle illegal chars in XML, encode InnerText
var doc = TransformXmlDocument(orgName, xmlDocs[0], xmlDocs[1]); 
var data = GetHashtableFromXml(doc); 
data = DecodeValues(data); // decode the values extracted from the hashtable
```

Regardless, I'm always looking for insight ... feel free to comment on this solution - or provide another.